# How to edit a facebook post in Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mechanize

I have a post on my fb page which I need to update several times a day with data elaborated in a python script. I tried using Selenium, but it gets often stuck when saving the post hence the script gets stuck too, so I'm trying to find a way to do the job within python itself without using a web browser.

I wonder is there a way to edit a FB post using a python library such as Facepy or similar?

I'm reading the [graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/post#Updating) reference but there are no examples to learn from, but I guess first thing is to set up the login. On the facepy [github](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) page is written that

> note that Facepy does not do authentication with Facebook; it only consumes its API. To get an access token to consume the API on behalf of a user, use a suitable OAuth library for your platform

I tried logging in with BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

def facebook_login(mail, pwd):
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get('https://www.facebook.com/', allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
action_url = soup.find('form', id='login_form')['action']
inputs = soup.find('form', id='login_form').findAll('input', {'type': ['hidden', 'submit']})
post_data = {input.get('name'): input.get('value')  for input in inputs}
post_data['email'] = mail
post_data['pass'] = pwd.upper()
scripts = soup.findAll('script')
scripts_string = '/n/'.join([script.text for script in scripts])
datr_search = re.search('\["_js_datr","([^"]*)"', scripts_string, re.DOTALL)
if datr_search:
    datr = datr_search.group(1)
    cookies = {'_js_datr' : datr}
else:
    return False
return session.post(action_url, data=post_data, cookies=cookies, allow_redirects=False)

facebook_login('email', 'psw')
```

but it gives this error

```
action_url = soup.find('form', id='login_form')['action']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I also tried with Mechanize

```
import mechanize

username = 'email'
password = 'psw'
url = 'http://facebook.com/login'

print("opening browser")
br = mechanize.Browser()
print("opening url...please wait")
br.open(url)
print(br.title())
print("selecting form")
br.select_form(name='Login')
br['UserID'] = username
br['PassPhrase'] = password
print("submitting form"
br.submit()
response = br.submit()
pageSource = response.read()
```

but it gives an error too

```
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 403: b'request disallowed by robots.txt'
```

Comment: Facepy uses an access token. You get an access token if you use the graph API to login. You don't get an access token if you login manually on facebook.com

Comment: @WizKid ok thanks, do you know where I can start in order to learn how to login with graph API in python? I'm trying with this https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-facebook-graph-api-and-extract-data-using-python-1839e19d6999

Comment: I would start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/

Comment: @WizKid thank you very much! i created my page access token and I was able to retrieve the message of my post, now I'm trying to add a comment to the post using `graph.put_object(parent_object=page_id+'_'+post_id, connection_name='comments', message='test')` but it says `facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action`.  I put the token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken and it says `Type: Page` and `Scopes: pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts, public_profile` so what is the problem?

Comment: @WizKid ok solved, i just had to add `pages_manage_engagement` to the permissions! now I'm trying to understand how to edit the post text, it seems that I have to use `graph.put_object(parent_object='post_id', connection_name = ???)` but I don't understand what I have to put as `connection_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the [`facebook`](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) package

```
pip install facebook-sdk
```

then to update/edit a post on your page just run

```
import facebook

page_token = '...'
page_id = '...'
post_id = '...'
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = page_token, version="2.12")
fb.put_object(parent_object=page_id+'_'+post_id, connection_name='', message='new text')
```